# Sending JSON to Jquery is failing

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Im having a problem with my php/jquery script. The PHP script is suppose to get an array of fields from a MySQL database, then parse it to JSON and echo it so that i can grab it in my Jquery script.

The problem is that the Jquery script is not grabbing the data correctly, or it is not handling the JSON correctly - or the last possibility that I am doing something wrong (which might be the case because Jquery is a new field of work for me).

I have tried a lot of different Jquery scripts i found on the internet, but here is my current code:

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
     include("../../config.php");
     $roomId = $_POST['roomId'];

     $data = mysql_query("SELECT field FROM fields WHERE room = '$roomId' 
        AND value = 1 AND TYPE = ''") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($users = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
        echo json_encode($users);
    }
?>
```

**The Jquery script:**

```
function UpdateRoom() {
    var data = 'roomId='+roomId;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: "chatfunctions/getplacementfield.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            var arrayValues = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(arrayValues, function() {
                $('#f' + parseInt(arrayValues.field).append('<div id="user" />');
             });
        }
    }); 
}
```

Anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong. If this is bad Jquery or PHP then tell me what's wrong as I mentioned earlier I am new to Jquery and not an expert in PHP.

PS: I am not getting any erros in the firebug console

Comment: You don't need `$.parseJSON()` - you've set `dataType: 'json'` so jQuery parses the response automatically before calling your success function. If that doesn't work there's likely something wrong with the way the PHP is sending it. I'm not a PHP guy, but I think `echo json_encode($users);` is wrong in that it echoes out individual pieces of JSON, one for each row. Inside the loop you need to somehow add each row to an array and then echo out a JSON encoding of the whole array after the loop ends.

Comment: Forgot to tell that the roomId variable in the jquery script is a global variable, and PHP is getting data from the MySQL database, so all good there

Comment: @nnnnnn -> okay that has been done, the data is now in an array and has been encoded to json, and sent back to the jquery, but still no result.. hmmm..

Comment: Have you checked the source code of the html, all you seem to be doing is appending empty divs (all with the same ID...).

Comment: This is bad JavaScript/PHP because it can be under SQL injection attacks. You should not use anything passed in from the client side inside a SQL statement without a validation. Also what you are passing is not JSON, proper JSON would be `JSON.stringify({ id : roomId });, Also you need not use a POST request here, change it to GET, then you will get a request like chatfunctions/getplacementfield.php?roomId=1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i hope you will get an idea from this eg. -

**PHP:**

```
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $dbs = mysql_select_db("rs", $con);

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile") or die(mysql_error()); 
  $json = array(); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  $json[] = $row;
  }

  print json_encode($json);   
  exit;

?>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){

    $.getJSON("userinfo.php",function(data)
    {
    $.each(data, function(i,data){
    var jsondata ="<li>Name : "+data.fname+" "+data.lname+"</li>";
    $(jsondata).appendTo("ol#userlist");
        });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting,

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

before you echo the json data.

You should also remove this line, var arrayValues = $.parseJSON(data); and pass data to the each function.  console.log(data) to check its an array of users.